# How to find a date at a specific word using regex

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
Sentence : "I went to hospital and admitted. Date of admission: 12/08/2019 and surgery of Date of surgery: 15/09/2015. Date of admission: 12/05/2018 is admitted Raju"

keyword: "Date of admission:"
```

Required solution: 12/08/2019,12/05/2018

Is there any solution to get the dates near "Date of admission:" only. Is there any solution

Comment: Your required solution seems to be asking only for dates immediately after `"Date of admission"` but one of them is a date from after `"surgery"`

Comment: @ddejohn Only date should be taken after Date of admission: Should not take Date of surgery:

Comment: Yes, but the second date in the "required solution" you provided is from after "surgery".

Comment: Sorry I have edited

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was unable to reproduce the result in the answer by @Ders. Plus I think `.findall()` is more appropriate here anyway, so:

```py
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"Date of admission: (\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})")

print(pattern.findall(s))
# ['12/08/2019', '12/05/2018']
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a [capturing group](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#grouping). If the re matches, then you can get the contents of the group.

```py
import re

p = re.compile("Date of admission: (\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})")
m = p.match(s)
date = m.group(1)
# 12/08/2019
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your result on my machine - `p.match(s)` returns `None` for me.

Comment: import re
s = "I went to hospital and admitted. Date of admission: 12/08/2019 and surgery of Date of surgery: 15/09/2015. Date of admission: 12/05/2018 is admitted Raju"
p = re.findall("Date of admission: (\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})")
print(p)

Comment: Cant able to use re.findall